# React A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined,

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as courseActions from '../../actions/courseActions';

class CoursePage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);

this.state = {
  course: {title: ""}
};

/*
 To enhance performance declare all the bindings here,
 otherwise if they are declare in the mark up binding
 will have to take place during rendering which will take
 performance hit.
*/

this.onTitleChange = this.onTitleChange.bind(this);
this.onClickSave = this.onClickSave.bind(this);
}

onTitleChange(event) {
const course = this.state.course;
course.title = event.target.value;
this.setState({
  course: course
  });
}
 onClickSave() {
this.props.dispatch(courseActions.createCourse(this.state.course));
}

courseRow(course, index) {
  return <div key={index}>{course.title}</div>;
}

render() {
return (<div>
  <div>
    <h1>Courses</h1>
    {this.props.courses.map(this.courseRow)}
    <h2>Add Course</h2>
  </div>
  <input
    type="text"
    onChange={this.onTitleChange}
    value={this.state.course.title}
  />
  <input
    type="submit"
    value="Save"
    onClick={this.onClickSave}
  />
</div>);
}
}

CoursePage.prototype = {
dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
courses: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
return {
  courses: state.courses
};
};

// since second parameter is not provided, connect ejects connect prop
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CoursePage);
```

Getting the following error, I am not sure why CoursePage would be considered a non-react component

```
invariant.js:44 Uncaught Error: CoursePage(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
    at invariant (invariant.js:44)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:166)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as mountComponent] (ReactPerf.js:66)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:39)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:297)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:222)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as mountComponent] (ReactPerf.js:66)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:39)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:203)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:628)
```

Comment: Your component looks right to me. Perhaps maybe it's to do with the fact that you are changing the prototype of CoursePage? If you want to use PropTypes, You should use `CoursePage.propTypes = { ... }` instead of prototype. In addition, propTypes are deprecated in react version >= 15.5. So you have to install it as a separate dependency.

Comment: That was the the issue, very good catch, I want to promote this to an answer.

Comment: I've added my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to do with the fact that you are changing the prototype of `CoursePage`. If you want to use PropTypes, You should use `CoursePage.propTypes = { ... }` instead of `prototype`. In addition, `propTypes` are deprecated in react version >= 15.5. So you have to install it as a separate dependency.